# Excel VBA code optimization for a nested loop and 18K rows

Tags: excel, vba

- Excel-VBA -
  I am current developing a VBA Excel macro for a warehouse counting controlling. Inshort:

1. I take data from Excel Warehouse DB dump with fields: "MSN", "Description", "Warehouse", "Location" and "Qty".
2. I dump the values first into an array called export_()
3. With a nested loop I lookup if there are matches as "MSN"&"Warehose"&"Location" in my table "tbl_wh"
   3.1 In case YES > I update "tbl_wh[Qty_update]" field and I fill the cell with the 2 last values + current value.
   3.2 In case NO > I add the new "MSN"&"Warehouse"&"Location"&"Qty" combination to the end of the table "tbl_wh" as a new entry.

Problem:The combinations "MSN"&"Warehouse"&"Location" are around 18K rows...
When this goes to the nested loop, the computer takes more than 10min for completing the task.
I am looking for advices to optimize the code.
My coding skills-experience are very basic so I am pretty sure this can be improved a lot.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Below code was simplified for better understanding!!

```
export_vector() >> array for store the report dump

For i = 1 To last_row_export

    For j = 1 To last_column_export
    
        export_vector(i, j) = export_sht.Cells(i + 1, j).Value
        
    Next j
    
Next i

For i = 1 To last_row_export

    ID_exists = False

    For Each rw In warehouse_sht.ListObjects("tbl_wh").ListRows

        If rw.Range(1) & rw.Range(3) & rw.Range(4) = export_vector(i, 1) & export_vector(i, 3) & export_vector(i, 4) Then
        
            ID_exists = True
            
            If rw.Range(5) = "" Then
            
                rw.Range(5) = "Qty: " & export_vector(i, 5) & " - Date: " & current_time
                rw.Range(5).Font.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
            
            Else
            
                split_qty = Split(rw.Range(5), "|")
                
                split_qty_last = UBound(split_qty())
                
                Select Case split_qty_last
                
                    Case 0
                        rw.Range(5) = split_qty(0) & " | " & "Qty: " & export_vector(i, 5) & " - Date: " & current_time
                        rw.Range(9) = export_vector(i, 5)
                        rw.Range(5).Font.ColorIndex = 7 'Purple
                    Case 1
                        rw.Range(5) = split_qty(0) & " | " & split_qty(1) & " | " & "Qty: " & export_vector(i, 5) & " - Date: " & current_time
                        rw.Range(9) = export_vector(i, 5)
                        rw.Range(5).Font.ColorIndex = 8 'Cian
                    Case 2
                        rw.Range(5) = split_qty(1) & " | " & split_qty(2) & " | " & "Qty: " & export_vector(i, 5) & " - Date: " & current_time
                        rw.Range(9) = export_vector(i, 5)
                        rw.Range(5).Font.ColorIndex = 46 'Orange
                End Select
            
            End If
        
            Exit For
        
        End If

    Next rw

    If ID_exists = False Then

        With warehouse_sht.ListObjects("tbl_wh").ListRows.Add
            .Range(1) = export_vector(i, 1)
            .Range(2) = export_vector(i, 2)
            .Range(3) = export_vector(i, 3)
            .Range(4) = export_vector(i, 4)
            .Range(5) = "Qty: " & export_vector(i, 5) & " - Date: " & current_time
            .Range(5).Font.ColorIndex = 10 'Green
            .Range(6) = export_vector(i, 6)
            .Range(7) = export_vector(i, 7)
            .Range(8) = export_vector(i, 8)
        End With

    End If

Next i
```

The macro is working good, the only problem is that I have more than 18K rows to analize under a nested loop.

Comment: Instead of putting the values directly into the range, add them to an array. The last step is to assign that array to the worksheet range. You might want a separate loop for the colorindex step

Comment: Is it possible to use conditional formatting rather than setting the color in VBA. I think conditional formatting is more efficient due to calculating based on when you actually show the cell. Of course, this requires that you can use formula to evaluate the color in the first place

Comment: An addition to Chill60's comment about doing things in one go: you can fill an array with all the values in one go as well, something like `Dim export_vector: export_vector = export_sht.Range(export_sht.Cells(2,1),export_sht.Cells(last_row_export,last_column_export)).Value`

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be:

1. Add "tbl_wh" the key column containing "rw.Range(1) & rw.Range(3) & rw.Range(4)".
2. Keep "tbl_wh" sorted by the key.
3. Use "Range.Find" method to find the key in "tbl_wh" instead of looping over it.